# Looking for explanation of a phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here's a phrase I've come across - ‘Philosophy is born of the merchant. Science is born of commerce. It's in relation to Europe's interaction with Americas in 1500s. I can't seem to figure out the nexus between terms given in the phrases. A mere guideline as to the tenor in which the phrases are meant to be, would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's philosophical musing.  (And keep in mind that "philosophy" and "science" were considered interchangeable terms at one time.)

Answer (score 2):

OP's cited "aphorism" seems to be from [modern French economist, writer ***Jacques Attali***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Attali), translation popularised by [British-Polish historian ***Norman Davies***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Davies).

As @Hot Licks says, *philosophy* and *science* were considered interchangeable terms at one time. But in [OP's exact context](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vD7SWb5lXBAC&pg=PA516&dq=%22Philosophy%20is%20born%20of%20the%20merchant%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JuEfVeSYKsq9abffgagK&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Philosophy%20is%20born%20of%20the%20merchant%22&f=false) that shouldn't matter - it's a modern text written for *current* readers.

As OP says, the *context in which Davies cites the text* is C16 interaction between Europe and America. Davies then expands on the significance of his citation by saying...

> *Henceforce, Europe is almost cut into two. The West is preoccupied with the sea. The East is preoccupied with itself.*

Attali's basic construction is ***A*** comes from **B**, and **C** comes from **D**, but since by definition *merchants* engage in *commerce*, ***B*** = ***D***, so we can simplify it to ***A*** and **C** come from **B**, giving...

> ***Trade*** [merchants+commerce] promotes both **philosophy** and **science**.

---

Personally I don't think it's a very good citation in context, because the point Davies is making is that Eastern Europe (without access to the sea, not easily able to engage in the emerging trade) *turned in on itself* - so we might think he means Eastern Europe thus became ***philosophical*** (as opposed to Western Europe which advanced more in ***science***).

In fact, I'd be pretty sure Davies (and Attali originally) see *philosophy* and *science* as both being domains where modern civilization ("The West") has made great strides in the past 500 years. Relatively speaking, Eastern Europe has been playing "catch-up" in those areas (that *really* matter), rather than willingly devoting themselves to spiritual matters and/or developing a better moral framework for human society.

---

TL;DR: Maybe Davies could have made up his own more appropriate aphorism for the context. If he'd asked me, I might have suggested...

> *Money talks. The more you talk, the more you learn - and **knowledge is everything.***

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, it has helped me surmise an opinion of my own on the given phrases. I think you make a good point about Easter-Europe becoming more philosophical and West more scientific. But it's not Davies' intention at this point to debase Eastern Europe. In fact, he may not be referring to Eastern Europe here at all. Terms such as Philosophy, Merchant Science and Commerce would sound much more felicitous, applied to West in Middle Ages than to East. I'd try to break down the terms' association with the prevailing events of the time - Merchants - Looking for novel <con>

Comment: ideas to multiply their profits. Science was coming of age - Sea voyages gave better understanding of the word to contemporaries, I believe first circumnavigation journey was made at time and the idea that earth was round came into acceptance. Commerce/trade was proliferating with import/ export from new world. Philosophy - it provided the enlightened minds to apply their knowledge to a wider view of word and mankind. It all relates to west. The East is busy with itself, having averted the Golden Horde's challenge and reorganising for the first time in a quincentenary. <cont>

Comment: So I think East doesn't get a mention here, only turbulence in the west at this point is being discussed.